# Parse API - Is it possible to send push notifications via Parse API without registering my user devices with them?

Tags: php, ios, api, rest, parse-platform

I am currently developing an iOS messaging app with PHP/MySql backend. I am saving device tokens of user devices with me on server. Is it possible for me to call Parse's REST API from my server to send push notification by providing it with device token, despite the fact that none of my users' devices are registered on Parse?

Answer (score 0):

The Push functionality on Parse uses the `Installation` class to send notifications. You device would need to have an entry in this table for Push to work correctly. You should save the deviceToken and associated data about the device to the `Installation` class on first install of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie with Parse.com, i red document from parse and using Rest API to created entry in Installation class. My problem is create push function to send notification to devices or user 
This is my code to upload installation data:

``` $installObj = $this->parse->ParseObject('_Installation');
$installObj->data = array(
    'deviceType'    => $data['device_type'],
    'deviceToken'   => $d``ata['device_token'],
    'channels'      => array('CHANNEL_TEST_ONE','CHANNEL_TEST_TWO')
);
$result = $installObj->save(); ```